# Why can't I curl this site? (php)

Tags: php, curl

This is my curl function, and It works very well until this site: http://www.finalpazarlama.com/kategoriler

```
 //Curl
function curl($site){
    $ch=curl_init();
    $maxredirect = 2;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $mr = $maxredirect === null ? 5 : intval($maxredirect);
    if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off')){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $mr > 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $mr);
    }else{
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        if ($mr > 0){
            $newurl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
            $rch = curl_copy_handle($ch);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            do {
                curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
                $header = curl_exec($rch);
                if (curl_errno($rch)){
                    $code = 0;
                }else{
                    $code = curl_getinfo($rch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                    if ($code == 301 || $code == 302){
                        preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
                        $newurl = trim(array_pop($matches));
                    }else{
                        $code = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            while ($code && --$mr);
            curl_close($rch);
            if (!$mr){
                if ($maxredirect === null){
                    trigger_error('Too many redirects. When following redirects, libcurl hit the maximum amount.',E_USER_WARNING);
                }else{
                    $maxredirect = 0;
                }
                return false;
            }
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
        }
    }
    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

When I try to work with http://www.finalpazarlama.com/kategoriler , it returns empty.
What could be the problem? Why can't I get it?

Comment: First, check their TOS, then, if you're actually allowed to access their site this way, my first **guess** is that you need to specify a user-agent.

Comment: maybe it's not allowed (like google.com)

Comment: This works for me. Might be a network issue on your end.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 157
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /PageNotFound?aspxerrorpath=/kategoriler
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
Date: Sun, 15 Sep 2013 14:25:06 GMT

That's the response, basically you are curling to a relative url that curl doesn't accept as valid i.e. /PageNotFound?aspxerrorpath=/kategoriler

you need to build the url to an absolute url 
I already have a function for that: https://code.google.com/p/add-mvc-framework/source/browse/project/trunk/functions/url.functions.php

feel free to copy those two to end up with something like this:

```
<?php
//Curl
function curl($site){
    $ch=curl_init();
    $maxredirect = 2;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $mr = $maxredirect === null ? 5 : intval($maxredirect);
    if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off')){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $mr > 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $mr);
    }else{
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        if ($mr > 0){
            $newurl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
            $rch = curl_copy_handle($ch);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            do {
                curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
                $header = curl_exec($rch);
                if (curl_errno($rch)){
                    $code = 0;
                }else{
                    $code = curl_getinfo($rch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                    if ($code == 301 || $code == 302){
                        preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
                        $newurl = trim(array_pop($matches));
                        $newurl = build_url($site,$newurl);
                    }else{
                        $code = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            while ($code && --$mr);
            curl_close($rch);
            if (!$mr){
                if ($maxredirect === null){
                    trigger_error('Too many redirects. When following redirects, libcurl hit the maximum amount.',E_USER_WARNING);
                }else{
                    $maxredirect = 0;
                }
                return false;
            }
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
        }
    }
    return curl_exec($ch);
}

/**
 * URL functions
 *
 * @package ADD MVC\Functions
 *
 */

/**
 * Returns the complete url according to $base
 *
 * @param string $base
 * @param string $url
 *
 * @since ADD MVC 0.5
 *
 * @version 0.1
 */
function build_url($base,$url) {
   $base_parts=url_parts($base);

   # https://code.google.com/p/add-mvc-framework/issues/detail?id=81
   if (preg_match('/^(javascript|data)\:/',$url)) {
      return $url;
   }

   if ($url[0]==='/') {
      return rtrim($base_parts['protocol_domain'],'/').$url;
   }
   if ($url[0]==='?') {
      if (!$base_parts['pathname'])
         $base_parts['pathname']='/';
      return $base_parts['protocol_domain'].$base_parts['pathname'].$url;
   }
   if ($url[0]==='#') {

   }
   if (preg_match('/^https?\:\/+/',$url)) {
      return $url;
   }

   return rtrim($base_parts['protocol_domain'],"/").$base_parts['path'].$url;
}

/**
 * Returns the URL parts of the url
 *
 * @param string $url
 *
 * @since ADD MVC 0.5
 */
function url_parts($url) {
   if (!preg_match('/^(?P<protocol_domain>(?P<protocol>https?\:\/+)(?P<domain>([^\/\W]|[\.\-])+))(?P<request_uri>(?P<pathname>(?P<path>\/(.+\/)?)?(?P<file>[^\?\#]+?)?)?(?P<query_string>\?[^\#]*)?)(\#(?P<hash>.*))?$/',$url,$url_parts)) {
      echo debug_backtrace();
      throw new Exception("Invalid url: $url");
   }
   return $url_parts;
}
echo "<xmp>";
var_dump(curl('http://www.finalpazarlama.com/kategoriler'));
```

Comment: Additional: On curl you can always check curl_error() for better debugging